# ElectonJs base64 image src - Failed to load resource

Tags: html, node.js, electron

In an electronJs app, I am trying to load a base64 image using the a dynamically created image tag. Appending the base64 string to image tag and appending it to the container using the method insertAdjacentElement(). I have tried setting the source using template string approach, concatinating no success.

When i run the app and perform the action of appending the image. In the console I get the error:
**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**
I have tried numerous base64 string but that is always the outcome.

```
const imgTemplate: HTMLImageElement = document.createElement('img') as HTMLImageElement;
                    imgTemplate.src = base64; // declared variable container base64 string

                    if(this._appThumbnailContainer) {
                        this._appThumbnailContainer.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', imgTemplate)
                    }
```

Below is a screen of the html in the DOM.
[image]

Further more in the network tab of the developer tools, it seems to be doing a fetch:

[image]

Comment: This question has more to do with Angular/Vanilla JavaScript than Electron. Shouldn't the format be, imgTemplate.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+base64;

Comment: How do you know it's angular? If you say vanilla I can agree. I have bootsrapped the application to use electron. And I am working with the electron api as well as node api to access filesystem and a module which generates the base64. There is no framework used, i simply have a file app.ts with the help of webpack to produce app.js.... Once the base64 string is returned onSuccess, I pass that to the newly created <img> tag src.


With the base64 as src value, electron seems to fetch this as a request resulting in "Failed to load response data"

@TomShaw going to try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an extra quote in the src string (`src="'`), re-check what your `base64` variable holds.

Comment: makes no difference whether the single quotes exist or not. I wrapped the base64 in single quotes before passing it to the src to see if it would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue to be related to a Content Security Policy meta tag I had added in the head tag of the index.html. This was added to get a round a particular issue related but found a work around for it without needing the meta anymore.

I commented it out to see if it would make a difference and yes it did.

Below is the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src *">
```